# is a permit required for changing old outlets

Tags: code-compliance

Do I need a permit to change old outlets out that are cracked or not working and replace them with new ones 
Thanks

Comment: For code questions you _really_ need to enter your location, at least down to the city.

Comment: Our municipality requires a permit for any repairs exceeding $50.

Comment: So a 2$ outlet or if you put a hospital grade outlet in at 18$ the answer is No.

Comment: You need to mention where you are from. In the UK, you need a certification to replace an outlet. In Germany you don't.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need a permit to replace fixtures or devices (outlets) with new ones.

Comment: I agree.  Replacing fixtures and devices falls under general maintenance and typically does not require inspection.

Answer (score 2):

It's not likely that a permit would be required, but the only way to know for sure is to contact your local building department.